# How to use in angular primeng event onLazyLoad?

Tags: angular, scroll, primeng

I'm trying to generate the onlazyload event in Angular but it doesn't generate itself, I have to start it with a click event, otherwise it doesn't work.

I tried this code:

```
<p-table [columns]="currentColumns" [value]="invoicesDataList" [scrollable]="true" [first]="0" scrollHeight="450px"
        [rows]="300" [virtualScroll]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [virtualScrollItemSize]="46" [lazy]="true"
        (onLazyLoad)="loadNextPage($event)">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of currentColumns" style="width: 20%;">
                    {{col }}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns="currentColumns">
            <tr style="height:46px">
                <td *ngFor="let col of currentColumns">

                    {{rowData[col.toLowerCase()]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>

    </p-table>
```

and then in my component try this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Luego, te suscribes al observable.
    this.onGuidUpdates();
    this.loadData({ first: 0, rows: 300 });

  }

  loadNextPage(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    this.currentPage++;
    this.loadData({ first: this.currentPage * 300, rows: 300 });
  }

  loadData(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    const pageIndex = Math.floor(event.first / event.rows);
    this.sharedService.fetchDataBasedOnGuid(pageIndex, event.rows).subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data["columnsUnited"].length > 0 && data["filesCommonResultList"].length > 0) {
        if (pageIndex === 0) {
          this.invoicesDataList = data["filesCommonResultList"];
        } else {
  
          this.invoicesDataList = [...this.invoicesDataList, ...data["filesCommonResultList"]];
        }
        this.totalRecords = data["totalRecords"];
        this.currentColumns = data["columnsUnited"];
      }
    });
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

For some reason it doesn't fire correctly, forcing it this way works but sometimes, and if I let it do it on its own the scroll event doesn't work, I don't know what I could be doing wrong.